# Python simple parser using tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

First ever code review post, so I hope I'm doing it right. My understanding of this site is that it is a place to post stuff like this for feedback and criticism. If that isn't the case, I apologise for my misunderstanding.

I'm teaching myself Python 3 and I'm pretty near the start. I couldn't find a simple description of a file parser, so I spent a frankly embarrassing amount of time trying to craft one, and this is the result:

```
def parse(file, startTag, endTag):
    bears=[]
    bearFile = open(file, 'r')
    for bearLine in bearFile:
        if startTag in bearLine:
            bear = bearFile.readline()
            while not (endTag in bear):
                bears.append(bear.strip())
                bear = bearFile.readline()
    return bears
```

I tested it using:

```
print(parse("bears.txt", "==start==", "==end=="))
```

...on a file which looked like this:

```
This file contains a list of bears.

Bears are below, between the start and end tags.

==start==
Grizzly
Polar
Koala
Panda
Spectacled
Sun
==end==

These are some more tags, listing some false bears:

==start==
Purple
Hairless
Aquatic
Flying
==end==
```

...and it works! The output is:

```
['Grizzly', 'Polar', 'Koala', 'Panda', 'Spectacled', 'Sun', 'Purple', 'Hairless', 'Aquatic', 'Flying']
```

With some obvious flaws, including:

1 - I can't work out how to ignore empty lines between the tags without using another if. I wondered if it might be better to do this later, and strip out all the '' entries, perhaps as an argument option.

2 - It depends on new lines because of the `readline` method, so using something else like a comma as a delimiter is currently beyond me.

3 - If there is no end tag, it loops forever. `try` and `except` are quite new to me right now.

I hope I'm not just wasting everyone's time by being here...

Comment: Not a full answer, but you never close `bearFile`.

Answer (score 5):

- Python has a style guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). I recommend that you follow it, as it makes your code easier to read.
  In this case it's mostly just using `snake_case`, rather than `camelCase`.
- You should use [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to automatically close the file. This happens in any circumstance.
- Rather than using `if startTag in bearFile`, I'd invert the if and `continue`.
- Rather than using `while` you can use `for` still. This, IMO, is easier to understand too.
- You could use a [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) so you don't have to write as much.

Along with a couple of name edits, here's how I'd change your code:

```
def parse(path, start, end):
    with open(path) as file:
        for line in file:
            if start not in line:
                continue

            for line in file:
                if end in line:
                    break
                yield line.strip()


print(list(parse("bears.txt", "==start==", "==end==")))
```

---

To address your concerns:

1. Do this out of the function. If you ever do want these empty values, then you'll be duplicating code. You also only need to use:

   ```
   [item for item in parse(...) if item]
   ```
2. You could implement a function, `split_delim`, that splits on a delimiter. If you make the function simple, then all you'd need to do is add one line to your function:

   ```
   def parse(path, start, end):
       with open(path) as file:
           file = split_delim(file, '\n')
           for line in file:
               ...
   ```
3. My changes should remove this error, due to how Python's `for` loops work. However I havn't tested this.

Comment: Regarding PEP8, this is a lot to study. Worthwhile of course, but my intention was to first focus on learning to make the code work, and then go to PEP8 a bit later on - _after_ the language makes a bit more sense to me, but _before_ I've gone long enough to start forming bad habits. Is there any reason this is a particularly bad idea? I'm sad to see snake_case favoured. I learned camelCase at University about 200 years ago and I find it prettier.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - what is the protocol here, do I mark this as "the answer" because I like the feedback, even though this isn't a question-and-answer situation? (Also I haven't seen `with` yet - the way it is used here doesn't make sense to me, so that's where I'm off to now.)

Comment: @fishkake From what I remember, PEP8 points can be split into two things. (1) style - mostly where and where not to put spaces. (2) code improvements, that people are likely not to do - using `with` with context managers. I think anyone can learn (1), where I agree (2) can be hard to learn. Python uses `CamelCase` for class names, and after a while it's easy to read both - I started with CamelCase too. The way the check works here is if you think it's helped you the most. And in this case it may also deter some feedback.